# Connect air conditioner to poppet valve

Tags: air-conditioning, pipe, valve, adapter

I am about to make a purchase for an air conditioner and I am consindering to connect the output to the existing exhaust air poppet/disk valve in my kitchen instead of using a window.

[image: A poppet valve]

My question is: how do I connect the pipes of the air conditioner to the valve? I can unscrew the disk but then how do I mount a pipe to it? Is there any pipe adapter for threaded puppet valves? I couldn't find it on my google search. What would be your approach to solving this?

I'm not an expert in any means, so please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: So you're going to vent the AC to an externally mounted poppet valve?  Make sure the exhaust pressure will open the valve. It seems like this will really reduce the flow of the AC venting.

Comment: How large in diameter is the poppet ?

Comment: [Beware single-hose portable A/C.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc)  They suck in hot humid air from outside, basically defeating their own reason to exist. Yes, I know they are more convenient, but they are horrible.